# Search get app crash in iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

I created an iOS application to search items from an `UITableView`. But when I type 'ag..','as...' and for several other occurances, suddenly app gets crash. It gives the exception

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 37 beyond bounds [0 .. 36]'

what can I do to solve this problem.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much tells you exactly what the problem is: the valid range for your mutable array is 0 to 36 and you're asking for element number 37.

I'm not sure whether you have an off-by-one error (i.e., you're counting from one rather than zero) or you're looking for an element that doesn't exist, but that's what your exception is.